# How do plot prediction, testing and training squancial data

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, lstm

My problem is I don't know how to use index as x-axis or how to fix the plot.

[training and testing df.head()s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LI9q.png)

[The plot that I want to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAeAp.png)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your code and avoid using URL lnks.

Comment: Dont know hot to do it

Comment: Instead of copy-paste of images, please copy paste the text of your code. Also try to reduce the code to only the part that is relevant for the question and try to add some dummy values for testing.

Comment: x=linspace(range(len(df)) plt.plot(x,prediction) plt.show()